# How to reduce the weight of an Excel workbook after gridview export in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, gridview

I've the following code to export my gridview in Excel :

```
 Protected Sub ExportToExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportExcel.Click
        Try
            Response.Clear()
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportEthias.xls")
            Response.Charset = ""
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Using sw As New StringWriter()
                Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

                GvActifs.BackColor = Color.White
                For Each cell As TableCell In GvActifs.HeaderRow.Cells
                    cell.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
                    cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
                    cell.ForeColor = Color.White
                Next
                For Each row As GridViewRow In GvActifs.Rows
                    row.BackColor = Color.White
                    For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
                        If row.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
                            cell.BackColor = GvActifs.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor

                        Else
                            cell.BackColor = GvActifs.RowStyle.BackColor
                        End If
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode"
                        cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
                    Next
                Next

                GvActifs.RenderControl(hw)
                'Le format de base est le texte pour éviter les problèmes d'arrondis des nombres
                Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
                Response.Write(style)
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
                Response.Flush()
                Response.End()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblMessage.Text = "Erreur export Excel : " & ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
        ' Verifies that the control is rendered
    End Sub
```

It Works fine but the Excel do 14,7 MB for 5k lines. It's to much :) 
How to reduce the weight of the export in Excel ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Excel files bloat when you do a lot of formatting. Even if you delete the formatting (colors, fonts) later it keeps the file size large. I see that you are formatting individual cells. Your file size will drastically reduce if you manage to write your code in such a way that you can format a range of cells at the same time. This is because this (pseudo-code):

`Cell A1: Bold`
`Cell A2: Bold`
`Cell A3: Bold`
`...`
`Cell Z3: Bold`

takes much more room to store in a file than:

`Range A1-Z5: Bold`

In this portion of your code:

```
If row.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
  cell.BackColor = GvActifs.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor
Else
```

You are coloring EVERY INDIVIDUAL cell, even though all your doing is alternating the row color. So why not color the row instead?

HTH!